# Azure-Devops: find in which branches a commit is contained

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

We have workitems in DevOps that have commits linked in them.

I open the Git commit in DevOps and would like to find information about which branches contain the commit.

How can I determine the branches for this commit?

[image: Commit information on DevOps]

Comment: What do you call "the" branch for this commit? There could be several branches pointing at it, or none. Commits don't belong to branches.

Comment: `git branch --contains $SHA` may be what you're looking for.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think your edit is confusing the issue. As mentioned in my answer, AzureDevOps shows either no branch, or exactly one branch there, regardless of how many branches contain the commit. I think rolling back that edit would probably make sense.

Comment: @TTT I think the question after my edit and your answer still make perfect sense together, if you write that azure does not allow seeing all branches at once, and that which one is displayed depends on from where you navigate to the commit.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I updated my answer to make more sense with your edit. That being said, I think OP's actual question was probably more along the lines of: "Why does a branch sometimes appear there and not other times?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: the question has been edited to make more sense in the context of Git because commits may exist on multiple branches, even though Azure DevOps will only show zero or one branches for any specific commit in the UI. To see all of the branches that contain a commit as the question is currently worded, you can use the command line:

`git branch --all --contains <commit-ID>`

For the original wording of the question, since commits can exist on zero to many branches, it doesn't make sense to display **the** branch that a commit exists on. (Perhaps it would if there was only one branch that a commit existed on, but that would not be the normal case in a typical repo.)

I just confirmed in Azure DevOps that when you view a commit directly, it does not display any branch information. However, **if you are viewing the history of a specific branch, and then click on a commit, you will see the branch name from which you viewed that commit**, and it appears in the exact location you specified in your screenshot. If you click the same commit from multiple branches you will see different branch names there depending on which one you clicked on the commit from.

Note that when a branch is displayed, the URL has additional parameters. Here are examples without a branch displayed, and with one displayed:

```
commit/aa2fa1e1c344b8b79e012a2b47acf32c445e94b2
```

vs

```
commit/aa2fa1e1c344b8b79e012a2b47acf32c445e94b2?refName=refs%2Fheads%2Fmy-branch-name
```

Comment: So is the answer: The Azure DevOps UI is bad and won't tell you what branch(es) a commit is in?

Comment: @DougMoore Hehe. I wouldn't say that. What are you envisioning it to look like? I don't know if any other UIs show that either, since you could have hundreds or even thousands of branches containing a commit. That's why it makes more sense to use the command line to list all the branches.

Comment: I mean, github does it. 

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/commit/34e80d86e8c0b754f6b7a02e307f53cb32806bbe

Using the command line does not "make more sense"

Comment: @DougMoore Interesting, I guess GitHub doesn't do it exactly like this question asks. It seems they don't list all branches if it's on the default branch, but do list (at least) one branch when it isn't. They also list all tags that contain that commit. To your point though, I agree that is pretty nice, and obviously more information than what AzDO provides.

Comment: @DougMoore OK- I found the documentation for this, [here](https://github.blog/2013-04-01-branch-and-tag-labels-for-commit-pages/). I'm so used to having this sort of information available from the command line that I never really cared to look in the UI for it. But I agree that's useful info when just looking around, especially if you haven't cloned the repo. Thanks for pointing that out.